# Books/Lecture notes about 2-categories.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, category-theory, book-recommendation, 2-categories

Are there good books or lecture notes just about 2-categories?(not about higher categories nor $\infty$-categories)

(I'm studying fibered categories for the descent theory of quasi-coherent sheaves. I want to understand fibered categories from 2-categorical view point.)

Comment: I took the liberty of replacing the tag "higher-category-theory" with "2-categories", as it seemed to fit the question better; but feel free to revert this if you want. By the way, are you only interested in (strict) 2-categories or also bicategories?

Comment: @ArnaudD. I'm a beginner at category theory, so I don't know relations between 2-categories and bicategories. As I wrote above, I want to get a perspective which gives well-understanding of fibered categories.Higher category theories may give it, but it is very heavy for me. So I want concise references about 2-categories for beginners. Therefore if theories about bicategories give me well-perspectives and is not heavy, I want to understand it.

Comment: For a (very brief) introduction to the 2-category of categories, see Emily Riehl’s \textit{Category theory in context} section 1.7. For a more involved introduction, you may see Borceux’s \textit{Handbook of Categorical Algebra}, Volume I Chapter 7. You may also look at Volume II, Chapter 8 for a discussion of fibered categories. You may also see “Fibered Categories and the foundations of Naive Category Theory” by Jean Benabou.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0412512v3) by Vistoli might be what you're looking for, especially chapter 3. For more discussion on 2-categories, see [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0702535). There are some more good resources in the references section of https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/2-category.

Comment: I'm jsut reading Vistoli's book. So the second reference is very kind for me. I'll try to read it.